# Magento 2 - Clear cache in 3 Servers programatically?

Tags: magento2, cache, reindex, server-setup

I am in a project which **uses 3 servers to serve a Magento 2 site**. I have **written a code to clear cache and re-indexing**. But for certain reasons the cache flush has to happen in all the three servers.
The reason i am looking for these approach **because after every csv product update we need to manually run all these commands**.
So, I am **looking for a programmatic approach** by which i can **trigger the re-indexing and cache flush commands after CSV product upload**.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Reindex the indexes and perform chache flush
 *
 */
 namespace Retailinsights\Testing\Controller\Index;

 class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

  protected $_indexerFactory;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory
  ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
  }

  public function reindexAll() {

    /* reindexs the following category */
    $indexer_ids = [
        //"design_config_grid",
        //"customer_grid",
        "catalog_category_product",
        "catalog_product_category",
        "catalog_product_price",
        "catalog_product_attribute",
        "catalogsearch_fulltext",
        "cataloginventory_stock",
        //"catalogrule_rule",
        //"catalogrule_product"
    ];

    foreach ($indexer_ids as $indexerId) {

        $indexerFactoryObject = $this->_indexerFactory->create();
        $indexerFactoryObject->load($indexerId);                
        $indexerFactoryObject->reindexAll();

        // destroy object
        unset($indexerFactoryObject);
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function cacheFlush() {

    $typeCollection = $this->_cacheTypeList->getTypes();

    foreach ($typeCollection as $type) {
        $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type->getId());
    }

    foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
  }

  public function execute() {

    /**
     *  reindex 
     */
    $this->reindexAll();
    /**
     *  Cache Flush
     */
    $this->cacheFlush();

    }
  }
```

Comment: you can create root file so after csv import  just hit the url in browser

Answer (score 0):

Create **reindex_cache.php** file into magento root directory and copy below code into that file.

**Url:** After csv import just hit the domain.com/reindex_cache.php in browser.

```
 <?php
    try {
        require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo <<<HTML
    <div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
            <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
            Autoload error</h3>
        </div>
        <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
    </div>
    HTML;
        exit(1);
    }


    error_reporting(1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $objectManager = $objectManager;

    // set whether frontend or admin
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

    // code for reindexing 
    $indexerCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory");
    $indexerFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory");

    $indexerCollection = $indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
    foreach ($allIds as $id) {
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }

// code for caching

try{
    $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
    $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
    $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
}catch(Exception $e){

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Sourav, If you closely look at my code above, i have implemented the same code as you have specified. Adding to that i was this code to get executed in all the 3 servers from one php file.

Comment: It may be risk to clean and re-index from database level.

Comment: Please  mark my answer so other take benefit from this.